# How do you leave a Stack Exchange community

Tags: support, uncommit

There are so many Stack Exchange communities that you don't always realize what you're getting into until it's too late, so my question is: How do you leave a particular Stack Exchange community that is already up and running without deleting your account?

If it is not a thing to leave a Stack Exchange community can you please add it?

Comment: Deleting **IS** leaving. You should simply delete your account only on the community you want to "leave" without deleting it on your other communities. You could also just hide a community from your list of communities without deleting your profile on that community by going to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/10964921/some-random-awesome-guy?tab=accounts).

Comment: The "without deleting your account" part is why I didn't vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. Whoever marked it as such as a slippery grasp on basic English.

Answer (score 9):

To delete your account, see [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).  You can delete your account just on that site without affecting others.  Deleting is permanent; if you decide to return to the site later you'll need to create a new account and start over.

Short of deleting, you can hide a community from view on your network profile, if you don't want the whole world to be able to see your participation in some site.  (They'll still see your profile on that site, but you can change names on different sites.)  Your account on that site isn't affected.

Other than that, all you can do is stop using the site.  You'll still get notifications from it, but I've found that sites I don't use much also don't generate a lot of notifications, and I can either handle or ignore the stray comment or rep change.

Comment: `create a new account and start over` So, is it safe to say there are no downsides to deleting your account on one site that you _just_ joined (possibly by mistake)?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed if you've done nothing with the account, then there are no downsides to deleting it and walking away.  If you've done something like spam the site, or if you're deleting so you can create a new account to get out of a ban or something, that would be different.  (Generic "you"; I know nothing about you personally and am not suggesting anything.)